# Which data in cached in yii after enable Yii

Tags: caching, yii

I checking out the Schema Cache part of Yii. Then I found the way for enabled via CFileCache and schemaCachingDuration. It is done without any problems. Now I am thinking as I did not specified which components should be cached. So Which part of application, Yii cached after enabled caching (In the way when we did not set any of other cache settings ).  It just schema or more ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Yii only caches:

- [Global state](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#setGlobalState-detail)
- [Translated messages](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n#translation)
- WSDL files of [Web Services](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.webservice)

All other cache features (schema caching, data caching, fragment caching, page caching) are only used on demand (i.e. if explicitely enable/use them).

Comment: So that means schemaCachingDuration settings tell application to do both cache schema + set expire duration instead of just set cache expire duration ?

Comment: Yes. The default is `0` which means, no schema caching.